# Azure Key Vault Secret URLs returns 404 Error when accessing from code behind ;

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

My key vault is hosted in North Europe region. When accessing the secret using the below code. I am getting a 404 error intermittently. It is working in morning and evening but at noontime 404 error is coming.  Is it related to any traffic issue ?

```
Dictionary<string, object> dictCredentials =  _dataManager.LoadAzureVaultCredentials(this._storageKey);

this._azureADApplicationClientID =  dictCredentials["Azure_AD_Application_Client_ID"].ToString();
this._azureADCertiicateThumprint =  dictCredentials["Azure_Certificate_Thumprint"].ToString();
this._keyVaultUrl = dictCredentials["Key_Vault_Url"].ToString(); 
int.TryParse(dictCredentials["Max_Azure_Retry_Attempts"].ToString(), out this._maxAzureRetryAttempts);
int.TryParse(dictCredentials["Azure_Retry_Attempts"].ToString(), out this._azureRetryAttempts); this.GetCert();

var kvConnectionString = new KeyVaultClient(new  KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(GetToken));

var retryPolicy = new RetryPolicy<ServerErrorDetectionStrategy(this._maxAzureRetryAttempts,TimeSpan.FromSeconds(this._azureRetryAttempts));
kvConnectionString.SetRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);

this._storageConnectionString = kvConnectionString.GetSecretAsync(this._keyVaultUrl).Result.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the code works at certain times of the day it's unlikely related to your code - open a support request in the portal or tweet @AzureSupport and they can dive a little deeper.